# QPushButton current opacity

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to animate fading in and fading out of QButtons. It works perfectly fine when I have preset opacity parameters as starting and ending values (for example 0 and 1, or 0 and 1). The code looks like this:

```
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
    qreal sValue=this->windowOpacity(); // **problem is here. It's always 1!**
    if(eValue>0) sValue=0; // **had to do this as temporary solution** 
    this->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
    QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(eff,"opacity");
    a->setDuration(duration);c
    a->setStartValue(sValue);
    a->setEndValue(eValue);

    if(sValue<eValue) a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InBack);
    else a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);
    a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

So, method `this->windowOpacity` always returns 1. No matter what. Also when I'm creating buttons and trying to set  `tbut->setWindowOpacity(0);` button is visible despite this. Clearly it doesn't work and I don't know why and how to easily manage this problem without creating additional property to button class.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell if your code is from custom QPushButton implementation (so `this` refers to QPushButton object) or the code is from some other `QWidget`.

You can have a look here:

```cpp
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->pushButton);
ui->pushButton->setGraphicsEffect(effect);

QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(effect, "opacity");
animation->setDuration(3000);
animation->setStartValue(0.0);
animation->setEndValue(1.0);
animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);

// To track opacity value
QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
timer->setInterval(250);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout,
        this, [animation]
{
   qDebug() << "Opacity: " << animation->currentValue().toDouble();
});

timer->start();
animation->start();
```

This code snippet does this:

[image]

And outputs this:

```
Opacity:  0.0693333
Opacity:  0.149
Opacity:  0.234333
Opacity:  0.319667
Opacity:  0.399667
Opacity:  0.485
Opacity:  0.565
Opacity:  0.650333
Opacity:  0.735667
Opacity:  0.815667
Opacity:  0.901
Opacity:  0.981
Opacity:  1
```

Instead of taking this value from `Button`, take that from `QPropertyAnimation` object.

Comment: My code works exactly the same. The problem is that I can't retrieve starting value opacity `animation->setStartValue(0.0)` from current object opacity, so I have to manually set 1 or 0.

Comment: Please have a look at updated answer - you can take opacity value from `QPropertyAnimation` object.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really what I need. My purpose is to set starting value of animation equal to current button opacity, so that I can pass only end value to function responsible for fading. Thanks a lot for making time answering!